# Accessing Parent Context in Polymer.dart

Tags: dart, dart-webui, polymer

I have problems accessing the parent scope inside the repeater.

The following code works:

```dart
<polymer-element name="x-playground" extends="div" attributes="children parent">
  <template>
    {{parent}}
    <template repeat="{{children}}">
      {{}}  
    </template>
  </template>

  <script type="application/dart">
    import 'package:polymer/polymer.dart';
    @CustomTag("x-playground")
    class PlaygroundView extends PolymerElement with ObservableMixin {
      @observable List children;
      @observable String parent;
    }
  </script>
</polymer-element>
```

But If I replace it with the following:

```dart
    <template repeat="{{children}}">
      {{parent}}
    </template>
```

it throws `variable not found: parent in 770699111`.

Is there a way to access the parent scope?

Comment: This is bug https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=12742 I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is bug https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=12742. Please star the issue to be notified when it's fixed. Thanks for the report!